# Dark regions at the bottom of MacBook screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, backlight

I've started seeing these dark regions at the bottom of my screen. They go away temporarily when I close the laptop, but come back every now and then. Is there an easy fix for this, or is there something wrong with my display?

[image]

Comment: @grg Flagging this question as duplicate is probably wrong. The linked question's subject is a single dark region. Here it's a regular pattern and seems related to another problem (already seen similar in the past; example: [MacBook Pro (Early 2008): Dark bands showing intermittently on built-in display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/TS1258)).

Comment: @klanomath Thanks, I’ve reopened it

Comment: Please add your MacBook Pro model number! Related: [Black shadows from the bottom of the screen](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/438327/Black+shadows+from+the+bottom+of+the+screen). Apple service program: [13-inch MacBook Pro Display Backlight Service Program](https://support.apple.com/13-inch-macbook-pro-display-backlight-service)

Comment: This is called “stage lighting effect” and it is caused by a faulty screen backlight (LED).  It may be possible to replace the backlight, but most likely, you have to replace the screen assembly.